# JavaScript: Gradually increase the value of a CSS property by 100 over 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element with the property `transform: translateX(0);` and the `translateX()` value gets increased or decreased by 100 on click via JavaScript. How can I make it so that this increase/decrease in value by 100 happens gradually, so it appears like the element is slowly moving?

This is how I'm currently changing it instantly:

```
val = val - 100;
var attplus = "translateX(+" + val + "%)";
scene[0].style.webkitTransform = attplus;
```

The element in question is `scene[0]` and the value is generated in the attplus variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add two more style properties for the [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) with 1s delay like:

```
var attplus = "translateX(+" + val + "%)";
scene[0].style.webkitTransform = attplus;
scene[0].style.WebkitTransition = "all 1s";
scene[0].style.transition = "all 1s";
```